How is it possible that man can sometimes dissuade HaShem if HaShem's will cannot be changed and He knows best?
For example, G-d wanted to annihilate the Israelites in ch. 32 of Shemot and yet, Moshe was able to change G-d's mind. This happens again Bamidbar 14. Yet, we see in Bamidbar 23 that G-d is not a man that He changes His mind, and it is often affirmed in Judaism that G-d always knows and does what's best. If that's the case, how can He be at times dissuaded, by a human being, no less?

This is a great question, but it's similar to: changing the decree in heaven by prayer. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@יהושעק This isn't a duplicate at all. The other question asks what the benefit is of a prayer that isn't answered. This question asks how can a prayer change God's mind. These questions are totally different, the only similarity is in the title (and also that the other question is based on an answer to this question).

@RabbiKaii Duplicates aren't a system of cross-referencing, they mean that the question is identical to another. "Source of the claim that Moshe's tefillah could change Hashem's mind" touches on the same theme, but it's not even remotely similar to what this question is asking.

@ba how about this? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29109/31534

This is also highly related, especially to the title of this question: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/66095/31534

@RabbiKaii Closer, but this question asks "How can Moses pray to God to change his mind if the Torah says God doesn't change" (a logical problem based on a contradiction between verses and the principle that God always does what's best), the other one asks "How can prayer ask God to change his mind instead of asking for a change in oneself" (a problem with a proposed answer to a separate logical problem on how God can change). (The other questioner's comments explaining why the answers don't answer his question should highlight one of the differences)

@ba well, I still feel the "logical problem based on a contradiction between verses and the principle..etc" is something extensively covered on this site. I haven't located a question, but it seems to be dealt with many answers to many questions, most of which come up with simple searches.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ba thanks for backing me up

@יהושעק Moshe didn't pray to G-d, he dissuaded G-d directly in conversation

@ddas91600 please don't take it personally - it's not personal and the sooner one understands that, the sooner one feels comfortable here. Of course, if we find a duplicate that answers your question, that would be best for everyone, including the person who asked

@RabbiKaii no hard feelings, I do hope you are able to find a duplicate that answers the question and even then, it seems a lot of users a voting to reopen this question

According to the Midrash (Beraishis Rabbah 53:4) G-d does change His mind for the better, if He finds a reason to such as prayer and repentance.

In the very example you brought, do our sages not infer from the verse that Hashem hinted to Moshe that he wanted to be "talked out of it"? See also the gemara in Pesachim about a prophet who didn't listen to the hint and didn't try to talk Hashem out of saving his people."What shall I do with this [clueless] old man?..."

https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.87a.13?vhe=William_Davidson_Edition_-_Vocalized_Aramaic&lang=bi&sbsq=%D7%9E%D7%94%20%D7%90%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94&with=SidebarSearch&lang2=he

The idea that Hashem does not change is very misunderstood. Rocks never change, statues never change. Of course this does not apply to Hashem, chas veshalom. Pretty much the main message of the Torah is that He is not a statue!
What it actually means is that He is perfect in every form of perfection, and cannot improve. He cannot become more patient, more just, more kind, more wise, more knowledgable etc. He is already the most patient, just, kind, wise and knowledgable possible - perfect in all forms of perfection!
So, if we ask His opinion on any matter, His opinion is also perfect, and will never change*! If He did change His opinion, that means His original opinion was not perfect. There was some flaw in His wisdom, His knowledge, His kindness etc, and it was pointed out, so He rectified it, and reanalysed and came up with a new opinion as a result, chas veshalom. So no, His opinions are perfect, and can never change.
Therefore, if we see Him have a new opinion on the same matter, the only possibility is that it's not actually the same matter. The matter has changed, and hence we are now hearing His opinion on this new matter.
For example, Hashem says "salachti kidvarecha" i.e. "I forgive you, because of your words", by the sin of the spies (Bamidbar 14:20). What changed? Moshe apologised, prayed, and thus the situation itself changed. Hashem's opinion didn't change about the same situation, but now that the situation changed, Hashem revealed a new opinion. When it comes to "sins of spies", if nobody apologises, Hashem's opinion is that they should be destroyed. If someone does apologise, His opinion is to spread the anger over many generations and galuyot, ultimately not destroying all but preserving a remnant - see Rabbeinu Bachaye on ibid 17**. This is also true of the incident with Moshe and the Chet HaEgel; see Rashi and Ramban on Shemot 32:10. Ramban reads עתה הניחה לי ויחר־אפי בהם ואכלם "leave me and I will pour my anger on them and destroy them" as "if you leave me and do not pray, then I will, but through your prayer, [which will change the situation] I will 'repent' and not destroy them".
This is really not too hard to understand. When my child does something very insolent, it makes me angry and feel he deserves to be punished, because I feel like he doesn't understand how wrong it is. However, if he apologises, he surprises me - turns out he did know how wrong it was. Suddenly I don't want to punish him anymore, in fact I want to reward him. Did I change my mind? No, I still agree that punishing him would have been right, if he didn't know what was wrong with what he did. It's just that I don't believe that anymore, because turns out it was never true. I "changed my mind", but I really didn't. The situation was different.
The truth is, humans do change their mind, because we are fallible. We can gain wisdom and knowledge, and lose it, and therefore make mistakes (like I did with my kid, above). We can be patient one day, and not the next. Our kindness goes up and down, as does our justice. If we are in the wrong mood, we punish, if we are in the right mood, we forgive. The lesson here is that this is not true of Hashem. He is always true, always patient, always perfectly kind and just. He can't gain knowledge or wisdom, nor lose it. Therefore His opinions are also all perfect, and do not change on a whim or a mood. If we see Hashem change His mind, look closer - He didn't, the situation changed.

There are tons of sources on this from all angles; Chakira (see Sefer HaIkkarim 4:18), Kabbalah (see Nefesh Hachaim 2:11), Chassidus (see Derech Mitzvotecha Ha'amanut Elokut 5-6***) and Mussar (see Michtav Me'Eliyahu, Volume IV, pages 79–81). This question is very related: If Hashem doesn't change, how does prayer work?, as are many many questions on this site. Just do a quick search for Hashem change, God change etc.

* if someone wishes to argue that there might be some interesting cases where there are 2 or more "perfect" opinions about the same thing, that would make for an interesting question its own right :)
** This source actually gives us an explanation on how to "change Hashem's mind" about something, i.e. exactly how to apologise, the right way, for the right sin, which Hashem taught Moshe at Sinai via the 13 Middot Rachamim
*** I would say this source is the clearest, and most detailed source for the main point of my answer, and strongly recommend it!

I think the distinction is that Hashem has an ultimate plan or objective which must come to pass, and this plan we cannot alter, however we can alter the way in which it plays out.
For example we daven that he forgive us; “אבל לא על ידי יסורים וחלים רעים, not by way of inflicting us with tragedy and sickness”. Rather, he figure out some other “less painful” way to forgive us.
So it’s clear that we can affect the method he uses to carry out his plans. However, I don’t think the Torah insinuates anywhere that we have the ability to change his ULTIMATE plans (for indeed they are good and perfect. Why would we want to?).
Hashem created the world with rules that even he abides by. Sometimes those rules allow us room to squirm in to his schemes, and sometimes it’s those very rules that make his actions solidified and unchangeable.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

So Hashem can change but only for small, insignificant things? Source please

I would suggest Derech Hashem 2:2-3 as a potential source for this line of thought
